# Is the last parameter of glVertexAttribPointer a '0' or 'None'?

Tags: python, opengl, glut, pyopengl, freeglut

I am trying to setup a simple 3D Engine in pyOpenGL. My current goal was to achieve a 2D rectangle being displayed to the screen, which isn't working at all. (nothing is being rendered to the screen, no exception is being thrown by the program.)

The render method I use is following:

```
 @staticmethod
    def render(model: RawModel):
        glBindVertexArray(model.get_vao_id())
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 1, model.get_vertex_count())
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glBindVertexArray(0)
```

I suppose something goes wrong with the glDrawArrays() method, because of how I bound my Buffer data:

```
@classmethod
    def bind_indices_buffer(cls, attribute_number: int, data: list):
        data = numpy.array(data, dtype='float32')
        vbo_id = glGenBuffers(1)
        cls.__vbos.append(vbo_id)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_number, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, 0)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_number, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, 0)`</s>

```py
glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_number, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
```

The type of the lase argument of [`glVertexAttribIPointer`](https://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glVertexAttribPointer.html) is `const GLvoid *`. So the argument must be `None` or `ctypes.c_void_p(0)`, but not 0.